# webpack cannot find module "."

Tags: angular, webpack

In my webpack.config.js

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  "URL": process.env.URL
})
```

and in my typing.d.ts, I declare URL

```
declare var URL: string;
```

like this. And in the ts file,

```
export const API = {
  URL: `${URL}/api/v1` || "http://127.0.0.1",
};
```

run my project, it has error in console

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
```

Comment: What have these snippets to do with each other apart from the three characters `URL` appearing in all of them.

Comment: webpack.config.js is the config file of webpack. And in typing.d.ts I declare global variable. In my ts file I define a const `API`, and in the other file of my project I can use `URL` with `API.URL`.